# Visible table after click submit

Tags: javascript, python, jinja2

I would like show table after click button submit. I made function hide table and onload in body and second function show table and put it in submit button . Then table is visible only moment. So it is bad solution.

Answer (score 0):

give your table a

```
display:none
```

in the css

then in Javascript , you capture the form submit , and change the display property of the element to block